# join 2 datarow rows into one row C#

Tags: c#, join, datatable, datarow

while i know i can make a join of 2 rows via sql, my program doesn't use it
i have 2 datatables and i take each row, compare to the rows on the other table and want to make a join out of it

```
 public DataTable joinTables (DataTable t1, DataTable t2)
    {
        DataTable joinTable = new DataTable();
        foreach (DataRow r1 in t1.Rows)
        {
            foreach (DataRow r2 in t2.Rows)
            {
                ///if (....)
                    joinTable.ImportRow(joinRows(r1,r2));
            }
        }
        return joinTable;
    }
    public DataRow joinRows (DataRow r1, DataRow r2)
    {
        DataRow joinRow = new DataRow();
        ///....
        return joinRow;
    }
```

Comment: Based on what criteria? What do you want the output to look like?

Comment: @DaveBish the criteria is non relevant (the "if") the problem is in joinrow() how can i join row to a row into a single row

Comment: @iakovl2, `the criteria is non relevant` is in short, **wrong**. When I have two rows who's schema matches, which row wins when a column value is different? You're creating **one row**.

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud my wrong then, i want a plain right/left join... row 1 is 1 2 3, row 2 is 4 5 6, the join is 1 2 3 4 5 6

Comment: @iakovl2 are you sure it's a left/right join then? Those types of joins take matching rows from only one side or the other and all rows from the adjacent side. Looks like you want a cross join. Can you confirm that?

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud well i understand it as a right/left join maybe cross also works, in both rows i check a field, in the field matches in both rows then i join them R1 (Ian, LAN, 35) R2 (TIB, IL,35) then Rjoin is (Ian,Lan,35,TIB,IL,35)

Comment: @iakovl2, **you have got to learn to be clearer and make sure you ask questions when people question the *criteria* because that is *by definition* criteria by which the rows are joined.** You can take my answer and modify it very easily to produce what you want -you just need to match the rows on the criteria in the outer most `for` loop.

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud joinRows() works only when it is called it doesn't check it the call was right it just takes 2 rows and make a single row out of them, that's why i try to tell criteria isn't relevant to it, it just gets 2 rows, return a single row

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of two ways to do join using LINQ.

```
        var t1 = new DataTable();
        var t2 = new DataTable();
        t1.Columns.Add("id", typeof (Int32));
        t1.Columns.Add("data", typeof (String));
        t2.Columns.Add("id", typeof (Int32));
        t2.Columns.Add("data", typeof (Int32));

        t1.Rows.Add(new {id=1, data="John"});
        t1.Rows.Add(new {id = 2, data = "Mary"});

        t2.Rows.Add(new {id = 1, data = "100"});
        t2.Rows.Add(new {id = 2, data = "200"});


        var results = from x in t1.Select()
                      join y in t2.Select() on (Int32) x["id"] equals (Int32) y["id"]
                      select (new {id = x["id"], name = x["data"], number = y["data"]});

        var lamdaResults = t1.Select().Join(
            t2.Select(), x => x["id"], y => y["id"],
            (x, y) => new {id=x["id"], name=x["data"], number=y["data"]});
```

Comment: this is if i know the type or count of the columns in each row. but in my case i don't know what is in each (there are several tables to choose from)

Comment: Then you shouldn't be using the term "join"

Answer (score 1):

I think you may have vastly underestimated the complexity of what you're looking for, but here is some code that will do it, but it has some major assumptions I'll discuss.

```
public DataTable joinTables (DataTable t1, DataTable t2)
{
    DataTable t = new DataTable();
    AddColumns(t1, t);
    AddColumns(t2, t);

    for (int i = 0; i < t1.Rows; i++)
    {
        DataRow newRow = t.NewRow();

        for (int j = 0; j < t1.Columns.Count; j++)
        {
            SetMergedRowValue(t1.Rows[i], newRow, j);
            SetMergedRowValue(t2.Rows[i], newRow, j);
        }

        t.Rows.Add(newRow);
    }

    t.AcceptChanges();
}

private void AddColumns(DataTable source, DataTable target)
{
    foreach (DataColumn c in source.Columns)
    {
        target.Columns.Add(string.Format("{0}_{1}", source.TableName, c.ColumnName), c.DataType);
    }
}

private void SetMergedRowValue(DataRow source, DataRow target, int index)
{
    var columnName = string.Format("{0}_{1}", source.Table.TableName, source.Table.Columns[index]);
    target[columnName] = source[index];
}
```

## Assumptions

1. Each `DataTable` has the same number of rows.
2. The rows in those `DataTable` objects are sorted in the order you want them merged by index.

These assumptions are major. In short, though this produces the desired outcome, I'm unsure it's **really** what you're looking for, and I'm unsure **you're** really sure what you're looking for.

Comment: that's too big of an asumption, the program i wrote works like a hash join, splits datatale to buckets then joins them.

Answer (score 0):

Alright all you mad lads out there, I think I've cracked it.

This is what I came up with for my problem, a bit of a pain in arse way of doing things, but it got the two datarows as one which is what I wanted.

Could not find anything as a default that did this, but please do let me know if it exists.

```
private DataRow JoinDataRow(DataRow r1, DataRow r2)
{
    // Get table columns
    var r1Cols = r1.Table.Columns;
    var r2Cols = r2.Table.Columns;

    // Create datatable to base row from
    var tempDataTable = new DataTable();
    foreach (DataColumn col in r1Cols)
    {
        tempDataTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(col.ColumnName, col.DataType, col.Expression, col.ColumnMapping));
    }

    foreach (DataColumn col in r2Cols)
    {
        tempDataTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(col.ColumnName, col.DataType, col.Expression, col.ColumnMapping));
    }

    // Create new return row to be returned
    DataRow returnRow = tempDataTable.NewRow();

    // Fill data
    int count = 0;
    for (int r1Index = 0; r1Index < r1Cols.Count; r1Index ++)
    {
        returnRow[r1Index] = r1[r1Index];
        count++;
    }

    for (int r2Index = count; r2Index < r2Cols.Count + count; r2Index++)
    {
        returnRow[r2Index] = r2[r2Index -count];
    }

    // Return row
    return returnRow;
}
```

An instance of how you could use it is perhaps using LINQ to join two separate data tables together and you want the rows to act accordingly, see example below:

```
var memberCompanyDetails = 
    (from DataRow member in members.Rows
    join DataRow company in companies.Rows on member["company"] equals company["company"]
    select JoinDataRow(member, company)).AsEnumerable().CopyToDataTable();
```